# How do I get setInterval to work with an array in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, setinterval

I want to run a function inside of a setInterval and change a variable for that function each time the setInterval runs, here is what I have so far:

```
$pages = new Array();
$pages.push("home.html","drp.html","drs.html","dffi.html","dci.html","dcp.html","drma.html","construction.html","orgChart.html");
$a = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $getPage = $pages[$a]
    $(this).getPageToLeft();
    $a++
    alert($a);  
},5000);
```

The problem is that $a is set back to 0 every time the setInterval runs, I need it to increase every time the setInterval runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was I used the wrong operator so I hope this helps sopmeone down the road:

```
// Auto Start
var pages = new Array();

pages.push("home.html","drp.html","drs.html","dffi.html","dci.html","dcp.html","drma.html","construction.html","orgChart.html");
var a = 1;
var int=self.setInterval(function(){flip()},5000);
function flip(){
    if (a === 9){
    a = 0;
    $getPage = pages[a];
    $(this).getPageToLeft();
    a++;
    }else{
    $getPage = pages[a];
    $(this).getPageToLeft();
    a++;
    }   
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#getDRP, #getDRS, #getDFFI, #getDCI, #getDCP, #getDRMA, #getConstruction, #getOrgCharts, .leftButton, .rightButton").click(function(){
        int=window.clearInterval(int)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pages = new Array();

pages.push("home.html","drp.html","drs.html","dffi.html","dci.html","dcp.html","drma.html","construction.html","orgChart.html");
var a = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    getPage = pages[a]
    //$(this).getPageToLeft();
    a++
    alert(a)
},5000);
```

This should fix your code.